# Checking existence of a $P(x,y)$ that satisfies a differential equation evaluated at reciprocals of itself and some other restrictions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Let $Q\in \Bbb K[x,y]$ be given. If
$$
\dfrac {\partial^2P}{\partial x^2}\left(\dfrac 1{P(x,0)^2,},0\right)+2\dfrac {\partial^2P}{\partial x\partial y}\left(\dfrac 1{P(x,0)P(0,0)},\dfrac 1{P(0,0)P(0,y)}\right)+\dfrac {\partial^2P}{\partial y^2}\left(0,\dfrac 1{P(0,y)^2}\right)=Q(x,y)
$$

As the field being considered is arbitrary, the derivatives here are [formal derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_derivative) (i.e, not defined by a limit).

Is there any way to check if there exists a $P\in \Bbb K[x,y]$ such that it satisfies the equation? And if it does exist, how could we retrieve it?

To give some context, this was an exercise my analysis professor left on the black board at the beginning of the year, to see if someone could solve it in that semester, and as expected, nobody could.

Comment: I'll probably add bounty on this when available.

Comment: What is $\mathbb K$?

Comment: An arbitrary field.

Comment: If $P$ is a function of two variables, how can you evaluate its derivatives at $1/P(x,0)^2$?

Comment: Oh right, I must have miscopied that from my notebook.